# C# WPF Draw OxyPlot in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, coordinates, oxyplot

I wanted to draw a coordinate system with OxyPlot in a UserControl. Unfortunately, there are two mistakes. I do not know why they are standing there. And this UserControl then later in my MainWindow when one presses on a certain button in the MainWindow application.

Can someone tell me where the error lies and fix it?

This works in another application. This is also not UserControl but MainWindow.

Errors:

- > "UCScreen" does not contain a definition for "Title", and you could
  >   not find a title extension method that accepts a first UCVoucher type
  >   argument
- > The name "creator" does not exist in the current context.

*I have marked the errors in the code with a comment*

UserControl

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Series;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Vorschau
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für UCVorschau.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UCVorschau : UserControl
    {
        public UCVorschau()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this; //Here is an error
            this.Title = "Vorschaubild";
        }

        public IList<DataPoint> Points { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Einstelungs-Fenster wird geöffnet
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        //btEinstellung


        private void btGenerate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime startZeit = DateTime.Now;
            Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

            double zufallszahlX;
            double zufallszahlY;

            double XMax = 10;
            double XMin = 0;
            double YMax = 10;
            double YMin = 0;
            // Zur Erstellung des Seeds
            int h = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            int m = DateTime.Now.Minute;
            int s = DateTime.Now.Second;
            String u = h.ToString() + m.ToString() + s.ToString();
            int iu = Int32.Parse(u);
            Random zufall = new Random(iu);
            Console.WriteLine("______________");
            CultureInfo en = new CultureInfo("en-US", false); // Damit ein Punkt ist anstatt ein Komma
            DataContext = this;
            this.Points = new List<DataPoint>();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(((Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\files\koordinaten.txt")), string.Empty);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(String.Format(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\files\koordinaten.txt"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    zufallszahlX = zufall.NextDouble() * (XMax - XMin) + XMin;
                    zufallszahlY = zufall.NextDouble() * (YMax - YMin) + YMin;
                    //Console.WriteLine("( " + zufallszahlX + " / " + zufallszahlY + " )" + " |" + i);
                    streamWriter.WriteLine("( " + zufallszahlX.ToString(en.NumberFormat) + " / " + zufallszahlY.ToString(en.NumberFormat) + " )" + " |" + i);
                    creator.addPoint(zufallszahlX, zufallszahlY); //Here is an error
                    Points.Add(new DataPoint(zufallszahlX, zufallszahlY));
                }
                ls.ItemsSource = Points;
            }
            Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            DateTime endZeit = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan gemesseneZeit = endZeit - startZeit;
           // statusbar.Text = "Gemessen Zeit für den Durchlauf: " + gemesseneZeit;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<UserControl x:Class="Vorschau.UCVorschau"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Vorschau"
             xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="461" Width="624">
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="461" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="624">
        <Button x:Name="btGenerate" Content="Generiere Koordinaten" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="409" Click="btGenerate_Click"/>
        <oxy:Plot x:Name="oxyPlot" Title="{Binding Title}" Height="245" Canvas.Left="298" Canvas.Top="32" Width="273" Background="#FFD1CFD0">
            <oxy:Plot.Series>
                <oxy:LineSeries x:Name="ls" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" LineStyle="None"  MarkerType="Square" MarkerSize="5" MarkerFill="Black"/>
            </oxy:Plot.Series>

        </oxy:Plot>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UserControl` class has no `Title` property but the `Plot` class has. You probably want to set this one:

```
public UCVorschau()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this; //Here is an error
    oxyPlot.Title = "Vorschaubild";
}
```

Or you should add a `Title` property to the `UserControl` class:

```
public UCVorschau()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this; //Here is an error
    this.Title = "Vorschaubild";
}

public string Title { get; set; }
```

Then the binding that you define in the XAML markup should work.

Regarding the "creator" I don't know what that is. Since you are adding the `DataPoint` to the `Points` collection you might as well remove this line I guess. Or you could add the `DataPoint` directly to the "ls" `LineSeries` that you have defined in your XAML markup:

```
ls.addPoint(zufallszahlX, zufallszahlY);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have removed this line and has worked without an error.